# Jest: Mocking files with different names

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have a file named `foo.js` that I want to mock, and instead of naming this file `foo.js` in the `__mocks__` folder, I am wanting to name it `foo.mock.js`. How can I do this with jest? Thanks!

```
| - foo.js
| - __mocks__/
    | - foo.mock.js
```

Answer (score 2):

```
| - foo.js
| - __mocks__/
    | - foo.mock.js
| - __tests__/
    | - foo.test.js
```

**foo.test.js**

```js
jest.mock("../foo", () => require("../__mocks__/foo.mock"))
```

This has worked for me